# Questions on rationals ordered by ascending denominator

Tags: sequences-and-series, continuity

Suppose that $f : [0, 1] \to\mathbb R$ and that $x_n, n=1\to\infty$ is the sequence of all rationals
ordered by increasing denominator
$0, 1,
1/2
,
1/3
,
2/3
,
1/4
,
3/4
,
1/5
,
2/5
,
3/5
,
4/5
,
1/6
,
5/6
, . . .$
and that $f(x_n) = n$.

1)Why do we know, without doing any calculation that
$f$ is not continuous? (This question does not ask for a precise proof, just an
explanation.). An answer that comes to mind is "just think of the graph", but it is probably not the explanation the question is looking for. On the other hand, proof seems easier to do here.

2) Where exactly do fractions greater than $1$ appear in $x_n$? Since we are listing all rationals, the would certainly have to appear somewhere. Is $x_\omega$, as in $\omega$ the ordinal number? (This is probably an abuse of notation.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the extreme value theorem, any continuous function on $[0,1]$ is bounded, but $f$ is clearly not bounded.  (Note that this is really essentially the same as user284331's answer--that answer is how you *prove* the extreme value theorem.)

As for your second question, when it says "all rationals" presumably it means "all rationals in $[0,1]$".  Since $f$ is defined only on $[0,1]$ we don't care about any rationals except the ones in that interval.

Answer (score 1):

There is a convergent subsequence of $(x_{n})$ by the sequential compactness of $[0,1]$, the values of the function at those subsequence elements become more and more larger and tend to infinity, as the denominator of them are growing, this violates the continuity.

Comment: You should mention sequential compactness of $[0,1]$, even though it may seem obvious.

Comment: I see, however we have not encountered sequential compactness yet, so I guess the answer the question is looking for is something else.

Comment: Anyway do you know that for bounded sequence it must have a convergent subsequence? This is known as Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem too, no need sequential compactness.